# Bootstrap 3.0 - push element to bottom

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I chose Twitter Bootstrap for quick app display layer bulding, recently I have faced problem.

I'm trying to push element to bottom of page container, but keeping it centered. Adding class
`.push-to-bottom { position: absolute; bottom: 50px }` didn't help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, the main problem was in my poor knowledge of CSS and Bootstrap convetions.
I found this solution acceptable, maybe it isn't the best approach, but it works, and it is fully reponsible.

```
<div class="container">
  <div id="home"> 
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-12">
        <h1>Some heading</h1>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>  
</div>
```

Main goal was to keep div fully centered horizontally, so #home div is wrapped inside container, then give the #home div position: absolute property, and then is simply change bottom property both fixed or given in percentage.

Answer (score 8):

If you know the dimensions of the element you want to center, you can use a margin-left being the negative value of width / 2. Like this [**jsFiddle example**](http://jsfiddle.net/thiagobraga/pwVLt/):

```css
.push-to-bottom {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 50px;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -50px;
}

#element {
  background-color: #000;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Use `position: absolute` to get it to the bottom of the page and use the `.text-center` class (from Bootstrap) along with `width: 100%` to get it in the middle:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row force-to-bottom text-center">
    <div class="col-xs-12">
            <h1>
            <input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="Save">
        </h1>

    </div>
</div>
```

```
.force-to-bottom {
  position:absolute;
  bottom: 5%;
  width: 100%;
}
```

[Clicky here for the fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/ninjaPixel/5fxbco88/2/)