# Position an element to the bottom using bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive

I know that you can position an element fixed to the bottom using the following css code:

```
position: fixed;
bottom: 0;
left: 0;
```

The problem is that the bottom content on small devices overrides the content that is above it. Does anybody know if bootstrap provides a responsive solution for this issue?

Comment: I don't thing so you can use [media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries)  in order to decrease the bottom content on small devices

Comment: add `margin-bottom` to the body or the content?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could always use !important. However you should probably be using a sticky footer. You need put the padding to the height of your footer on your body > .container. see here http://getbootstrap.com/examples/sticky-footer-navbar/.

Comment: I think the sticky footer is what I need. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 0):

```css
.force-to-bottom {
    position:absolute;
    bottom: 5%;
    width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootswatch/latest/journal/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">
    <div class="row force-to-bottom text-center">
        <div class="col-xs-12">
             <h1>
           <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button">Save</button>
          </h1>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Credits: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19072741/5192105

Answer (score 0):

If I understood the problem correctly, you can resolve it by giving your `body` a `margin-bottom` to resolve this issue.
Suppose you have a fixed `div` that has a `height` of `200px`.

Use:

```
body {
    margin-bottom: 200px;
}
```